# Qt: Are keyboard shortcut assignments (using "&") in Qt apps not working for Mac OSX?

Tags: c++, macos, qt, keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts

In a QDialog, keyboard shortcuts are supposed to be assigned by & and one is supposed to be able to tab through the widgets on the shortcut. For example (from Blanchette and Summerfield's book):

`caseCheckBox = new QCheckBox(tr("Match &case"));`

should assign "alt-c" as a shortcut to the checkbox in  a dialog. Neither tabbing through widgets, nor the & shortcuts seem to work when I compile my apps on a mac running OSX 10.6. Is this a known limitation of the Mac skin? Is there a workaround?

Comment: Did you use command key instead of alt on Mac OS X? On Mac OS X all shortcuts are performed with command key: http://www.onedigitallife.com/images/apple-command-key.jpg

Comment: Kamil Klimek: mnemonics (underlined letters) are not the same as shortcuts (Ctrl+C etc.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the Qt 4.8 documentation:

> On Mac, shortcuts are disabled by default. Call
>   qt_set_sequence_auto_mnemonic() to enable them.

See the [QShortcut documentation](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qshortcut.html#mnemonic) for details.